# Closing Xamarin forms Navigation Drawer

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I just started with Xamarin forms and followed  [this](https://github.com/varunpsr/xamarin-forms) example. But for the landscape mode it always has Navigation drawer opened. Is this default behavior? Below is my code

```
  public class NavigationDrawer : MasterDetailPage  // Navigation Drawer using MasterDetailPage
{
    public override bool ShouldShowToolbarButton()
    {
        return true;
    }

    ContentPage gotoPage;
    public NavigationDrawer()
    {

        Title = "Navigation Drawer Using MasterDetailPage";
        string[] myPageNames = { "Camera2 Demo", "Second", "Third" };
        SizeChanged += NavigationDrawer_SizeChanged;
        ListView listView = new ListView
        {
            ItemsSource = myPageNames,
        };
        this.Master = new ContentPage
        {
            Title = "Options",
            Content = listView,
            Icon = "hamburger.png"
        };

        listView.ItemTapped += (sender, e) =>
        {

            switch (e.Item.ToString())
            {
                case "Camera2 Demo":
                    gotoPage = new CameraPage();
                    break;
                case "Second":
                    gotoPage = new SecondPage();
                    break;
                case "Third":
                    gotoPage = new ThirdPage();
                    break;
                default:
                    gotoPage = new NavigationPage1();
                    break;
            }

            Detail = new NavigationPage(gotoPage);
            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
             this.IsPresented = true;

        };

        Detail = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
        IsPresented = false;

        //// For Windows Phone, provide a way to get back to the master page.
        //if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone)
        //{
        //    (this.Detail as ContentPage).Content.GestureRecognizers.Add(
        //        new TapGestureRecognizer((view) =>
        //        {
        //            this.IsPresented = true;
        //        }));
        //}
    }
```

Question

1) How would I control opening and closing of Navigation Drawer? I found a way where it would give us control over the width of the navigation Drawer. [Here](http://www.meritsolutions.com/mobile-development/implementing-navigation-drawer-in-xamarinforms/) is the Link. But is this the best option available right now?

1) Since project requires to be crossplaform Xamarin forms controls seems to be one of the option.

2) Should we go with Custom controls and not Xamarin forms controls?

I just started with Xamarin sample code would appreciate if someone can guide me through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set `MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover` on the MasterDetailPage to force it to exhibit the behaviour you are after, otherwise it will default to `MasterBehavior.Default`, which in Landscape mode will be always open.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) How would I control opening and closing of Navigation Drawer?

Use `this.IsPresented = true;` to open and `this.IsPresented = false;` to close the drawer.
About the other questions I don't understand you good, but depending on your requirements, you should create custom controls or download one from `NuGet`.

**Note:**
I believe the most important thing for a beginner is to learn how to implement a native code using `DependencyService` and also to use Design patterns like **MVVM**.

Comment: So if using MVVM then create a property IsPresented (with INPC) in your ViewModel and bind the MasterDetail page's IsPresented property to it using Mode=TwoWay, then from the ViewModel you can just set it to True/False when you need to without worrying about interfering with its default behavior.